# The semantics of storing the subtraction of two unsigneds to a signed

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

I am subtracting to unsigned numbers and storing them to a signed type, and it just works. An I do not fully understand why this just works. Take the following example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        uint32_t a = 1;
        uint32_t b = 2;
        int32_t c = a - b;
        printf("%"PRId32"\n", c);
        return 0;
    }
```

The result of this subtraction is -1, and it seems like it is only -1 because my computer is two's complement. Am I correct? I am looking at the C11 specification.

If we disect the following statement:

```
        int32_t c = a - b;
```

We start with, according to operator precedence (as stated by annotation 85 on page 76), the subtraction:

```
a - b
```

C11 6.5.6/6:

> The result of the binary - operator is the difference resulting from
>   the subtraction of the second operand from the first.

This is -1 and thus will not fit. Conversion!
C11 6.3.1.3/2:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.

So the actual value of `a-b` is `4294967295`. Next up, the assignment operator: C11 6.5.16.1/2:

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted
>   to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored
>   in the object designated by the left operand.

So the unsigned value `4294967295` needs to be converted to a signed value. What are the rules?
C11 6.3.1.3/3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

So this is fully implementation defined and thus ends up being -1, since that is how my implementation is.

Is this really the case? Would the code result in a different value if I run it on a system with one's complement system? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: `int32_t` is defined to be 2's complement (C11 7.20.1.1/1) so -1 would be the most natural implementation-defined conversion from 4294967295 to an `int32_t` value, although there is nothing to stop an implementation doing something else. Also, if `int` can represent all values of `uint32_t`, the result of the subtraction will be -1 regardless.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito No, `a` and `b` will be converted to `int` first due to integral promotion IIRC.

Comment: @L.F. Oh, so true.  Too many inconsistencies to rely on implicit conversions.  :)

Comment: @L.F. Indeed! See 6.5.5/4: If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on them.

Comment: Re “So this is fully implementation defined and thus ends up being -1, since this is just the case in a two's complement system”: That is not a valid inference. The result of the conversion is implementation-defined, and C implementations that use two’s complement often define the result of an overflowing conversion to a signed type to effectively use the low bits, but they are not required to, so you cannot infer that. Another reasonable behavior an implementation might choose is to generate an overflow signal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, I clarified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The result of this subtraction is -1, and it seems like it is only -1 because my computer is two's complement. Am I correct?

Before lvalue conversion upon assignment, the result of the actual operation `a - b` is `4294967295` = `2^32 - 1` = `UINT_MAX`, because the subtraction is carried out on `uint32_t` operands and wrap-around is well-defined, according to the 6.3.1.3/2 rule that you quote. You will get `4294967295` regardless of which signedness format your system uses.

> Is this really the case?

Yes, you've read and quoted the standard correctly.

> Would the code result in a different value if I run it on a system with one's complement system?

Yes. Raw binary of this is number is `0xFFFFFFFF` and so the impl.defined conversion to signed is very likely translating it to the signedness format's corresponding representation of this raw binary:

- On a 2's complement system, `0xFFFFFFFF` gives `-1`.
- On a 1's complement system, it would give `-0` which is possibly a trap representation.
- On a signed magnitude system, it would give `-2147483647`.

Other forms are not allowed (C17 6.2.6.2/2).

> Or am I overlooking something?

One little detail. Unlike C's integer conversion rules, the `int32_t` type specifically is crap-free. It is *guaranteed* (7.20.1.1) to always be using 2's complement and no padding bits. An exotic signedness system with 1's compl. or signed magnitude would not easily be able to support the `int32_t` - it is actually an optional type, only mandatory for 2's complement implementations. So your code would not compile if 2's complement wasn't supported.

Also please note that strictly speaking, the correct format specifier for `int32_t` is `"%"PRId32` and not `%d`.

Comment: `a - b` is not necessarily `4294967295`. If `INT_MAX >= UINT32_MAX` then both operands will be converted to `int` by the integer promotions and the result will be `-1`. Otherwise, if `UINT_MAX >= UINT32_MAX` then both operands will be converted to `unsigned int` by the integer promotions and the result will be `UINT_MAX` (which by necessity would be the same as `UINT32_MAX` in this case).

Comment: @IanAbbott It is perfectly safe to assume that 32 bit numbers are not small integer types and that `int` is not 64 bits or larger. No such systems exist and are not likely to ever exist either, because they would come with such a low quality of implementation that they would be useless in practice.

Comment: I agree that it's *very likely* that the `uint32_t` to `int32_t` conversion performed upon assignment is representation-preserving. As far as the standard is concerned, however, its behavior is **implementation defined** when the value assigned is outside the range of (signed integer type) `int32_t`, and thus could be different.  In particular, a signal might be raised.

Comment: @Lundin I kind of agree about your assumptions in practice, but not from a language-lawyer perspective. (IANALL)

Comment: The format specifier is `%"PRTi32"` (as a complete replacement for `%i`).  The `"` will "cancel out" with those of the `PRIi32` macro which may be defined as `#define PRIi32 "i"`.  Having therefore these preprocessing steps:  `%"PRIi32"` -> `%""i""` -> `%i`

Comment: @Lundin: There are some applications for which it might be convenient to be able to configure the sizes of `int` and `long`.  Compilers for the 68000 used to routinely allow `int` to be configured as either 16 or 32 bits, and I see no reason why compilers that bundle their own Standard Library implementations couldn't practically offer a 16/32/64 choice for `int` and 32/64 for `long`.

Comment: @supercat Yes, this is also common with 16 bit microcontrollers. Been there, done that - it is not convenient. Because then you start relying on some non-portable, compiler-specific setting. And then you import some 3rd part lib which uses `int` and it stops working because they had made assumptions about data type sizes. Perhaps not explicit assumptions about the range of `int` itself, but on subtle crap like which type small integer types get implicitly promoted to. That's exactly why there's few excuses not to use stdint.h in modern C programming.

Comment: @Lundin: The availability of compiler options means that code using either `int` type can be dealt with.  If one's compiler defines macros so that e.g. `abs` becomes `__abs16` or `__abs32` depending upon the size of `int`, then one can even mix and match compilation units with both `int` sizes unless one needs to pass a `va_list` or have multiple compilation units use standard library functions without including the proper headers.  As for promotion issues, `<stdint.h>` does nothing to fix those.

Comment: @Lundin: If the Standard had specified e.g. `uwrap32_t` which, if supported, would be a non-promoting 16-bit integer, and `unum16_t` which, if supported, must promote to a longer signed type, then compilers with any size `int` could have been augmented to support such types, but code which uses such types would be usable on existing compilers (with no modification beyond the inclusion of such types to `<stdint.h>`) where types meeting those requirements already exist.

Comment: @supercat The difference with stdint.h is that you can chose to be portable without sacrificing performance. Take `1 << 15` which is dangerous on a 16 bit system but fine on a 32 bit system. If this is rewritten as `1U << 15` and `int` happens to be 32 bit, it might result in slower code. Whereas `(uint16_t)1 << 15` will run fast on a 16 bit system, and if ported to a 32 bit system, the silent integer promotion of `(uint16_t)1` to `int` is harmless, because `1 << 15` is fine on a 32 bit system, but UB on the 16 bit system. ->>

Comment: Or if we want to be fancy, we can even do `(uint_fast16_t)1 << 15` and always get the best result, completely portable.

Comment: @Lundin: So what should one do if one wants to compute `(x*y) mod 4294967296`?  One could use `((x+0ULL)*y)`, but the fixed-width types don't help with that.  A sufficiently weird hardware platform could even support `uint32_t` and yet have 
 something like `uint32_t x; ... x++;` invoke UB in the wrap-around case if its `int` and `unsigned` types have 33 data bits, balanced out by padding bits.

Comment: @Lundin: Correction: `((x+0u)*y)`.  On systems where `unsigned` is 32 bits or smaller, and `x` and `y` are `uint32_t`, the computations would be performed on `uint32_t`, but on those where `uint32_t` is bigger, they'd be performed as `unsigned`.  The authors of the Standard expected that anyone seeking to make a quality compiler for a commonplace platform would process e.g. `uint1 = ushort1*ushort2;` in a way that works for products between `INT_MAX+1u` and `UINT_MAX`, but gcc demonstrates that that's merely because they lacked imagination.